# I can not build Javascript with webpack --mode=development or --mode=production (Node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path 
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. You'll almost certainly need to provide more information, like the complete relevant log file info, how you're invoking anything, configs, etc.

Comment: The command you used might be incorrect? Webpack can't find the file you're trying to build?